# button.click() in javascript not working in chrome

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net

I have a button and click functionality is written in its code behind.
It followes as

//javascript code

```
document.getElementById('btnUpload').click();
```

.cs code

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UploadFile();
}
```

Now in case of IE10 it works and calls the .cs function 
but in case of chrome or firefox it only calls button's clientside functions and not the server side one.

Comment: what's the code for the button?

Comment: When you manually click the button - does the postback happen? Also what are the button's attribute at that time - is it disabled by any chance?

Comment: It is defiantly not disabled.

Answer (score 1):

If your button is an asp control you meed to get the client id.
Try `document.getElementById("<%=btnUpload.ClientID%>").click();`

Answer (score 0):

please try

```
document.getElementById("<%=btnUpload.ClientID%>").click();
```

or

open button1 properties and ClientIDMode property can switch to Static and change javascript code

```
document.getElementById("buttonId").click();
```

please review

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode(v=vs.110).aspx